# How to traverse this hash within one line?

Tags: ruby, hash, enumerable, ruby-1.9.3

Each key in a hash has a value that's also a hash.

```
    {
      100 => {
        1 => 'ruby',
        2 => 'enumerables'
      },
      50 => {
        3 => 'can',
        4 => 'cause'
      },
      15 => {
        5 => 'occassional',
        6 => 'insanity'
      }
    }
```

For each hash object, I want to discard the top-level key, and replace it with the key and value of the nested hash objects.

```
{
  1 => 'ruby',
  2 => 'enumerables',
  3 => 'can',
  4 => 'cause',
  5 => 'occasional',
  6 => 'insanity'
}
```

I have it working, but my method uses a `merge!`, and requires creating another hash to store the values. I'm curious to see if it can be done in one line. I tried to use `reduce()`, but could not make it work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works:

```
hash.values.inject(&:merge)
```

**Edit:** Another option, using `reduce` (which is the same as `inject`), and noting tokland's comment that to_proc is automatically called when you use a symbol:

```
hash.values.reduce(:merge)
```

Then it becomes not only concise but very readable.

Comment: +1 I never knew that `Symbol#to_proc` handled arity > 1 blocks like that!

Comment: note that `inject` accepts a symbol: `hash.values.inject(:merge)`. Using functional `Hash#merge` is absolutely ok, but it creates a new hash on each step; since `hash.values` is a newly created and temporal array I guess it wouldn't be too heretical to write `hash.values.inject(:update)` if the input can be very, very large.

Comment: Thanks @tokland for the reminder that `to_proc` is done for you by `inject`/`reduce`. And good point about `:update`.

Comment: @tokland The array is newly-created, but the values of the array are still the original hashes. Using `update` is fastest (see benchmark in my answer), but it certainly does mutate the first hash in the original data.

Comment: @Phrogz: my bad, I assumed (wrongly) that Array#values returned a copy of the values. But that's not the case so using `update` directly on them is not such a good idea. We'd need to clone the first value in the array, but the code wouldn't be not so pretty now...

Answer (score 5):

I like the answer by @MarkThomas best, but for speed and memory efficiency I suggest:

```ruby
flatter = {}.tap{ |h| original.values.each{ |h2| h.merge!(h2) } }
```

Benchmarking 200,000 iterations of the current answers shows this to be the fastest:

```
                          user     system      total        real
Phrogz                0.710000   0.020000   0.730000 (  0.728706)
Joshua Creek          0.830000   0.010000   0.840000 (  0.830700)
Mark Thomas symbol    1.460000   0.020000   1.480000 (  1.486463)
Mark Thomas to_proc   1.540000   0.030000   1.570000 (  1.565354)
Tim Peters            1.650000   0.030000   1.680000 (  1.678283)
```

Since the comment by @tokland—`original.values.reduce(:update)`—modifies the original hash we cannot compare it directly to the other methods. However, if we modify all tests to put a duplicate of the first hash back into the original each iteration, @tokland's answer becomes the fastest, though still not quite as fast as mine:

```
                          user     system      total        real
tokland's destroyer   0.760000   0.010000   0.770000 (  0.772774)
Phrogz                1.020000   0.020000   1.040000 (  1.034755)
Joshua Creek          1.060000   0.000000   1.060000 (  1.063874)
Mark Thomas symbol    1.780000   0.040000   1.820000 (  1.816909)
Mark Thomas to_proc   1.790000   0.030000   1.820000 (  1.819014)
Tim Peters            1.800000   0.040000   1.840000 (  1.827984)
```

If you need absolute speed and it's OK to modify the original values, use @tokland's answer. If you do so and want to preserve the original unmerged hashes unscathed, then you can:

```ruby
first_k,orig_v = original.each{ |k,v| break [k,v.dup] }
merged = original.values.reduce(:update)
original[first_k] = orig_v
```

*Note that your question title says **traverse**; if you don't really want to merge the values—if you might want to visit a duplicate key twice instead of last-in-wins—then simply do:*

```ruby
original.values.each{ |h| h.each{ |k,v|
  # hey, we're traversing inside!
} }
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if traverse was the right word, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: My answer is presumably what you had, except that I'm showing you how to use `tap` to make it officially one line. :) But again, this is twice as fast as the more-fun solutions.

Comment: I wonder if @tokland's `hash.values.reduce(:update)` would be faster than mine.

Comment: @MarkThomas Thanks for the impetus to check. It is!

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't value about the top level keys, use #values to get an array of the values (in this case, also hashes).  Then you can use #inject to build up a new hash, merging them as you go.

```
yourhash.values.inject{|hash, thing| hash.merge(thing)}
```

There are probably other ways to do it.

Answer (score 3):

```
Hash[original_hash.values.flat_map(&:to_a)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just took a stab at it, first try was brute force and better methods (in both senses of the word...) are out there.

```
h.map {|k,v| v}.inject({}) {|i,h| i.merge(h)}
```

Answer (score 2):

While it isn't as brief as some of the other answers, I think `each_with_object` deserves a representation.

```
output = input.each_with_object Hash.new do |(_,subhash), hash|
  hash.merge! subhash
end
```

Comment: Note that using `each_with_object` like this is functionally equivalent to using `tap` as I did, yet it is more typing and always a little slower than the `tap` version.